# Monero public key generation

Tags: cryptography, viewkey, privatekey, javascript

I'm trying to get the public key with different JavaScript libraries: with [elliptic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic) and with [libsodium-wrappers-sumo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsodium-wrappers-sumo) This is my code:

```
const BN = require('bn.js');
const EdDSA = require('elliptic').eddsa;
const ed25519 = new EdDSA('ed25519');
const _sodium = require('libsodium-wrappers-sumo');

(async() => {
  await _sodium.ready;
  const sodium = _sodium;
  
  const privKeyHex = "6220f3affaa568f554ca850f9374e7112c09af219976bb779f4fd8f297294900"
  const tmp1 = sodium.crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(Buffer.from(privKeyHex, "hex"), "hex")
  const tmp2 = ed25519.curve.g.mul(new BN(privKeyHex, "hex", "le")).getY().toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 32).toString("hex")

  console.log(tmp1)
  console.log(tmp2)
})()
```

I expect to get the same values ​​but I get different:

```
e96c5156a431383f12014f320e4bdeae441ad2d36e0364278a36d9b4e5f99ffa
e96c5156a431383f12014f320e4bdeae441ad2d36e0364278a36d9b4e5f99f7a
```

The last byte is different. Inexplicably.

Checking on [this site](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) gives the result:

```
e96c5156a431383f12014f320e4bdeae441ad2d36e0364278a36d9b4e5f99ffa
```

What could be the reason for the discrepancy between the results and what is the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [RFC8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-5.1.2) for an explanation of how the sign of a point is encoded into the most significant bit of the last byte. By doing `getY()` you're attempting to do your own encoding, and not setting this bit.

Instead, let the library do the encoding for you:

`elliptic.utils.toHex(ed25519.encodePoint(ed25519.curve.g.mul(new BN(privKeyHex, "hex", "le"))))`